# Custom code folding for bash scripts in intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

Was hoping there was a way to collapse long lines of code in idea while in a bash script. As i have a base64 image that i write to a file, as well as some other text that gets written for set up, and it would be lovely if there was a way to collapse it. Ive tried `#<editor-fold desc="image">` but that doesnt seem to work.
On Mac

Answer (score 1):

You can simply select any block in a file and use Fold Selection (Ctrl-. in the default keymap). IntelliJ IDEA will remember the folding region and its status even if you restart it.

Answer (score 0):

As per yole's answer above, i found that the selection for collapsing in macOS is `command .` and it does indeed keep the collapse for later. Thanks